# React not responding to emit from server [Socket IO]

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io, io

Okay so i have no prior knowledge about Socket IO so please bear with me if my question i really stupid ;-; Any help at all is appreciated.

Basically what I'm trying to do is have my React front end get a 'signal' from the server. So I have an socket.emit('task-data-changed') server side and an 'io.on('task-data-changed)' on the front end but this does not seem to do anything and i have no idea why.

Here's my server side code:

```
const app = express();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.origins('*:*');

io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on("task-data", () => {
    console.log('got task-data signal on the backend');
    socket.emit("task-data-changed", 'everyone');
  });
  
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
```

Here's my React code:

```
useEffect(()=> {
    Socket.on("task-data-changed",() => {
      console.log('task data was changed on the backend');
    });

    return () => Socket.off("task-data-changed");
  },[]);

const submitNewTaskHandler = () => {
   console.log('trying to emit  task-data');
      Socket.emit('task-data');
}
```

Things i know are working i guess:

1. The server logs 'a user connected' and 'user disconnected' appropriately when we load to localhost and when the page closes.
2. Inside 'submitNewTaskHander', the console.log() runs properly as well as the Socket.emit('task-data')
3. I know the above thing because the server is able to get the 'task-data' signal and then logs 'got task-data on the backend' properly.

the problem is after that the socket.emit('task-data-changed') on the server-side and the Socket.on('task-data-changed') don't seem to be working.

Thank you for reading so far, apologies if I've used the wrong terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code to set the event listener on your front-end socket seems fine:

```
useEffect(()=> {
    Socket.on("task-data-changed",() => {
      console.log('task data was changed on the backend');
    });

    return () => Socket.off("task-data-changed");
  },[]);
```

But, my question to you is, why is that code inside of `useEffect()`? You should put it wherever your Socket is originally made. Or, you could put it on the line just before `Socket.emit('task-data');`

To give some explanation, Socket.on() is a listener. In your case, it listens for 'task-data-changed'. Once you tell it to start listening, it will keep listening forever. So, you should just set the listener up once by using Socket.on(), and you usually do this right when you initialize the Socket. Just do it once and it will stay listening and running your callback function.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the quick response. I put the socket.on call inside the useEffect of the component that creates the socket originally and its working so thank you :) The reason i had put it inside useEffect() is as useEffect() runs only for the first time when React renders the component and if I would place it inside any other function it would call socket.on(...) every time something changes on the page and that would call a whole bunch of listeners with nothing closing them.  I did try it tho and it gave the expected behavior.

Comment: Also this does solve the problem of the front end being able to detect the emit, however if i have two tabs open and a change is made in the first tab only the first tab is able to detect the emit. Is there anything i should be adding to the server side so anyone using the site is able to detect the emit?

Comment: Without seeing your code I can't be sure. My guess is your Socket.on() isn't being attached (or maybe Socket doesn't even exist?).

Comment: Try a simple console.log("its attached if you see this"); Socket.on(() => {...});